# MongoDB C# 2.0 Driver SetSerializationOptions

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have updated C# MongoDB Driver to 2.0

Now `SetSerializationOptions` is not working. Following is the old code.

```
cm.GetMemberMap(m => m.ArrayField)
      .SetSerializationOptions(
          new ArraySerializationOptions(
                new RepresentationSerializationOptions(BsonType.ObjectId)));
```

Please help me with the replacement for above code in 2.0 Driver?

Answer (score 0):

The new documentation covers this here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/#serialization-options.

You need to set a new serializer that is configured appropriately for your scenario.

Craig

Answer (score 0):

Working code for MongoDB.Driver 2.14.1, might help anyone

```
public class Document 
{
    public string[] ArrayField {get; set;}
}

BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Document>(cm =>
{
    cm.MapMember(m => m.ArrayField)
        .SetSerializer(
            new ArraySerializer<string>(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId))
        );
});
```